# Android Nested Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to implement `nested fragments` but I have a problem.

When I add 2 different `fragments` with two different `tags` ("tag1", "tag2") in a `ChildFragmentManager` of one `fragment`, everything seems to be ok.

But when I call `getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag` on these `tags`, only the first `fragment` is returned. I'm getting `null` on the second one.

To add `fragments` I use:

```
PersonsImageFragment imf = new PersonsImageFragment(imgPreview, 1);
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = frag.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frame, imf, "tag1")
                        .addToBackStack(tagName)
                        .commit();
imf = new PersonsImageFragment(imgPreview, 2);
transaction.add(R.id.frame2, imf, "tag2")
                        .addToBackStack(tagName)
                        .commit();
```

Am I missing something ?

**EDIT:**

```
    f = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag1");
//    f.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    f = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag2");
 //   f.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

**EDIT 2:**

What I'm trying to do is that, I have `ViewPager` and in one of the `fragments` I have `custom view`, that is responsible for taking a picture and showing it in the `ImageView`. So the `nested fragment` is calling `camera intent` and in `onActivityResult` it is updating the `ImageView`. As you know there's a `bug` in `Nested Fragments`, I have to call manually the `onActivityResult` of the `nested fragment` from the `Parent Fragment`. So in Parent's `onActivityResult` I'm trying to get the `nested fragment` I need and call its `onActivityResult`.

**EDIT 3:**

As I said, I have `Custom View`, that is responsible for taking picture and showing it off. I have 3 `Custom Views` in the Parent `Fragment` `Layout`. And when the user clicks any of them, it should take a picture and preview it. If I add only 1 `custom view` to the parent `fragment` it works, but when I use 3  of them, the `click event` works on all of them, that mean that camera `fragment` is attached but I can't call `onActivityResult` on other two because I can't get the `fragment` that `startedActivityForResult`, it is `null`. So the problem, in my opinion, should be in adding `nested fragments` to `transaction` but I can't find it.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're calling findFragmentByTag?

Comment: You are calling transaction.add() twice, while adding the same exact fragment twice.  Why not create 2 separate fragments then?  Otherwise, your second option is to use transaction.replace() to swap the fragment.

Answer (score 3):

I can't really be sure since the source code is not 100% complete, but I think there a couple of things being mixed up.

For example, you're reusing the same `PersonsImageFragment` for both fragments and also the transaction. Try something like this:

```
PersonsImageFragment frag1 = new PersonsImageFragment(imgPreview, 1);
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = frag1.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frame, frag1, "tag1")
                        .addToBackStack(tagName)
                        .commit();

PersonsImageFragment frag2 = new PersonsImageFragment(imgPreview, 2);
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = frag2.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction2.add(R.id.frame2, frag2, "tag2")
                        .addToBackStack(tagName)
                        .commit();
```

Haven't tried it out so you might need to modify it a bit to compile, but you get the idea. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I'll add some stuff to the question.